# Chrome Extension chrome.storage.sync.get undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that requires users to enter their own key that must be saved in the extension's options. However, whenever I try to run options.js, it gives me the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.restore_options (options.js:15)

I have updated the permissions in the manifest.json and have reloaded the extension and restarted the browser. This is my first chrome extension but I have looked through all the tutorials and other questions related to this issue and cannot figure out what I have done incorrectly.

Here is my code:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Web Acknowledgement",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*",
        "file://*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "private_keys.js",
        "jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "icons": {

  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

options.js:

```
  var api_key = document.getElementById('apikey').value;

  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    apiKey: api_key,
  }, function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('save');
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  });
}

function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    apiKey: '',

  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('apikey').value = items.apiKey;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
    save_options);
```

Comment: I guess you probably look at the list of errors in chrome://extensions page in which case it's an old error so click the `clear all` button to remove it. Or maybe you open options.html directly as a file, which is wrong: you should open it from the extension icon menu or from chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried "clear all" to check and see if it was an old error, but when loading the options page again, the error reappeared. And to clarify, I am not loading the options as a file, I am loading it from the icon menu as you said.

Comment: You have two `permissions` in manifest.json so I guess the second one without `storage` wins.

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't catch that! Just changed it and it worked! Thank you so much!